# Get request url in feign client interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am using spring feign client for making http requests.

Fiegn configuration class

```
DefaultConfig.class
public class DefaultConfig {

    @Bean
    public OkHttpClient client() {
        return new OkHttpClient();
    }

    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.FULL;
    }

    @Bean
    public Decoder feignDecoder() {
        return new JacksonDecoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public Encoder feignEncoder() {
        return new JacksonEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
        return template -> {
            template.header(Authorization, apiKey);
        };
    }
}
```

My client interface:

```
@FeignClient(name = "default", url = "${base-url}",
        configuration = DefaultConfig.class)
public interface {

    @PostMapping(value = "/users/")
   Response createUser(@RequestBody Map<String, ?> requestBody);

    @GetMapping(value = "/users/{id}")
   Response getUserDetails(@PathVariable String id);
    

}
```

The thing is now I need to use different authorization key for GET and POST request. In the configuration class I need to differentiate the request by url called. How can we get the url the requester interceptor or any other way we can achieve this. We can create separate interceptor for this but I try to use the same interceptor for both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you need seems to be in the template object.

```
@Bean
public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
    return template -> {
        if ("GET".equals(template.method()) {
            template.header(Authorization, apiKey);
        } else {
            template.header(Authorization, differentApiKey);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need seems to be in the code below.

```java
@Bean.
public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
    return template -> {
        template.request().url() // this is request url which is from feign!
        template.requsst().httpMethod() // this is request method!
    };
}
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining the overall approach / what the code is doing.